# migration of a question to Physics.SE

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

I'd like to migrate this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50037/2987) to Physics.SE and I'd appreciate some help in doing so. thank you

Comment: More migration requests, flagging for moderator attention is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Done.